# Font Awesome hover of stacked icons not working properly

Tags: css, css-selectors, font-awesome

I am facing a Problem regarding the hover effect of my icons.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-wrench fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my style:

```css
.fa-circle {
    color: red;
}
.fa-circle:hover {
    color: blue;
}
```

The hover is working until I hover the inner icon (`fa-stack-1x`). As soon as I hover the `fa-stack-1x` the `fa-stack-2x` loses the hover style.

How can I prevent the `fa-stack-2x` to lose its hover style with only CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to capture the hover event on the container span ".fa-stack" like that:

```
.fa-circle {
            color: red;
        }
.fa-stack:hover .fa-circle {
            color: blue;
        }
```

here is a working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/fou3om77/

Answer (score 1):

You will need to target the parent element for the `:hover` selector, since there is no way of targeting previous elements:

```
.fa-stack .fa-circle {
    color: red;
}
.fa-stack:hover .fa-circle {
    color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because your hover is only defined on the `.fa-circle` element and not either of the `.fa-stack-1x` elements. If you wish to target all the icons you'll need to place the hover effect on the `fa-stack` parent:

```css
.fa-stack .fa {
    color: red; /* All icons within the fa-stack are red by default. */
}

.fa-stack:hover .fa {
    color: blue; /* All icons within the fa-stack are blue when hovered over. */
}
```